# Where to set breakpoint in Django for a request (before being dispatched)?

Tags: django, debugging, breakpoints, pdb

Where is a good place to set a breakpoint in Django at the point where a page request comes in, but before the Django dispatcher has run?

I assume there's a loop in the Django web server (`manage.py runserver`) where it's waiting for requests?  Or maybe somewhere outside the web server but within the Django url dispatcher where it decides which code to call from urls.py?  (Note that I don't want a breakpoint for a specific page, but for any given page)

Comment: Perhaps you could set a break in one of your views then look at the call stack to see where you might better place it?

Comment: Great idea, @Aidan_Ewen.  I tried that and the call stack makes it clear.  But strangely, I then set breakpoints at 3 of the lines in the stack, but they don't get triggered.  I will open up a separate question for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In django/core/handlers/base.py (version 1.4.2), the function `get_response` does exactly what it says.

Lines 100/101 determine which view to use using your url conf:

```
callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = resolver.resolve(
    request.path_info)
```

Comment: Thanks Iain_Shelvington, just what I was looking for.  Curiously, I set a break there, but it never gets triggered.  I'll open up a separate question for that issue.

Comment: Rob, in the same file on line 175, any exception (which is how I assume you are implementing breakpoints) is caught by a catch-all except statement. Even if you re-raise the exception there is another catch-all on line 189.